# onClick events on li items, to change textFields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, webserver

I am trying to implement an onClick event on `li` items. Every time this is event is triggered, it will change some text in a div to some preset text I have in javascript. However I cannot get it working. I have tried asking this on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/444s51/using_an_onclick_event_triggered_by_li_to_change/) as well.

The code displayed bellow can be also found in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzzdLvm5/3/)

```
<body>

<div id="header">
<h1>THE BODAK</h1>
</div>


<ul>
  <li><a href="history.php">Back</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link" id="link" >Anthony</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link2" id="link2" >Ben</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link3" id="link3" >Jacob</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link4" id="link4" >Jesse</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link5" id="link5" >Karmar</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link6" id="link6" >Mitchell</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').on('click', function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = "Anthony";
    document.getElementById("anthony").innerHTML = "Alias: Lysander Lucretius II";
    document.getElementById("anthony2").innerHTML = "A human cleric who worships Verum-Die, speaks many languages and talks much better than he hits. Has been seen with a black gem and a white gem lodged in his chest.";
    });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".link2").click(function(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = "Ben";
    document.getElementById("anthony").innerHTML = "Alias: Nishi Kani-Orc Garland-Human";
    document.getElementById("anthony2").innerHTML = "Not much is known about the rogueish character, it is known though that he is sneaky and acrobatic. He has been seen feeding a cat, and has said he will not use his shape-shifitng abilities to commit crimes.";
        });

});

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".link3").click(function(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = "Jacob";
    document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = "Alias: Max";
    document.getElementById("anthony2").innerHTML = "The large half-giant is crippled and bound to a magic chair, however this giant has mastery over some sort of telekenetic arts.";
        });

});

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".link4").click(function(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = "Jesse";
    document.getElementById("anthony").innerHTML = "Alias:Kuso Oma";
    document.getElementById("anthony2").innerHTML = "The age isnt the only mystery sourrounding this women, seemingly being able to summun demon-like abilities at will and laughing in the face of danger. Has stated her race comes from deep underground.";
        });

});

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".link5").click(function(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = "Karmar";
    document.getElementById("anthony").innerHTML = "Alias:Zota";
    document.getElementById("anthony2").innerHTML = "A human cleric who worships Verum-Die, speaks many languages and talks much better than he hits. Has been seen with a black gem and a white gem lodged in his chest.";
        });

});

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".link6").click(function(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = "Alias:Drudder";
    document.getElementById("anthony").innerHTML = "Alias: Lysander Lucretius II";
    document.getElementById("anthony2").innerHTML = "This drow definitely practices some dark arts, but has already risked his life to save one of the groups memebers. Was caught in some shady dealings with rat-folk.";
        });

});


</script>

    <h2>Anthony</h2>
    <div id="anthony" style="word-wrap: break-word; width: 100%" >Alias: Lysander Lucretius II</div></TD>
    <br>
    <div id="anthony2" style="word-wrap: break-word; width: 100%" >A human cleric who worships Verum-Die, speaks many languages and talks much better than he hits. Has been seen with a black gem and a white gem lodged in his chest.</div></TD>
    <br>

</body>
```

Comment: You've been given some good advice on reddit. Why have posted the exact same code on here without updating as suggested on there? You're also using jQuery, but the library isn't attached to you jsfiddle. There's also some invalid HTML.

Comment: your updated fdidle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzzdLvm5/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle does not include jQuery, so that is why it's not working. However, you have several issues which can be addressed.

Firstly, you only need to use one `document.ready` handler. All your code can be placed in there. Secondly, if you follow DRY principles then you can use a single event handler for all elements if you separate out the individual information for each one in to `data` attributes, like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="history.php">Back</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="link" id="link" data-title="Anthony" data-alias="Alias: Lysander Lucretius II" data-bio="A human cleric who worships Verum-Die, speaks many languages and talks much better than he hits. Has been seen with a black gem and a white gem lodged in his chest.">Anthony</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="link" id="link2" data-title="Ben" data-alias="Alias: Nishi Kani-Orc Garland-Human" data-bio="Not much is known about the rogueish character, it is known though that he is sneaky and acrobatic. He has been seen feeding a cat, and has said he will not use his shape-shifitng abilities to commit crimes.">Ben</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="link" id="link3" data-title="Jacob" data-alias="Alias: Max" data-bio="The large half-giant is crippled and bound to a magic chair, however this giant has mastery over some sort of telekenetic arts.">Jacob</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="link" id="link4" data-title="Jesse" data-alias="Alias:Kuso Oma" data-bio="The age isnt the only mystery sourrounding this women, seemingly being able to summun demon-like abilities at will and laughing in the face of danger. Has stated her race comes from deep underground.">Jesse</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="link" id="link5" data-title="Karmar" data-alias="Alias:Zota" data-bio="A human cleric who worships Verum-Die, speaks many languages and talks much better than he hits. Has been seen with a black gem and a white gem lodged in his chest.">Karmar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="link" id="link6" data-title="Alias:Drudder" data-alias="Alias: Lysander Lucretius II" data-bio="This drow definitely practices some dark arts, but has already risked his life to save one of the groups memebers. Was caught in some shady dealings with rat-folk.">Mitchell</a></li>
</ul><br><br><br><br>

<h2 id="name">Anthony</h2>
<div id="alias">Alias: Lysander Lucretius II</div><br>
<div id="bio">A human cleric who worships Verum-Die, speaks many languages and talks much better than he hits. Has been seen with a black gem and a white gem lodged in his chest.</div><br>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').on('click', function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        $('#name').text($el.data('name'));
        $("#alias").text($el.data('alias'));
        $("#bio").text($el.data('bio'));
    });
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/jzzdLvm5/8/)

Comment: Thank you friend. I also realised part of my problem was not having jquery library available on my pi. When I fixed that your solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li').click(function(){
   $('h2').text($(this).find('a').text());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jzzdLvm5/9/

You select by the `a` tag where you click and put the text inside the current `h2` text (more logical than `div` now)

Comment: This only works by taking the value out of the <a> though. How would this work with changing the div to the long strings of text I want. I cant take them from the <a> like your method.

As in as far as I can tell this only works for the headers.

Comment: @AnthonyDrury what about now

Answer (score 1):

You can use "this" object to get the label name & change it for h2 as told by Thomas and for the rest of text use switch case or else if ladder to check for conditions instead of these many JS functions & use the jquery method $(#id).text() to set texts for the field in that switch case, it'll be easy.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  $('h2').text($(this).text());
    if(id == "link"){
        $('h2').text($(this).text());
      $('#anthony').text("sample text for link.");
        $('#anthony2').text("detailed text.");
    }else if(id == "link2"){
        $('h2').text($(this).text());
      $('#anthony').text("sample text for link2.");
        $('#anthony2').text("detailed text.");
    }...so on
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your javascript code in one document.ready() event,and make sure you are referencing existing HTML tags/elements in your script, for example .

```
$document.ready(function(){

  $('a').click(function(){
     document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = "Anthony";
 });  
});
```

-The on click should be tired to the child element of the list item you are clicking, in this case it is the anchor 'a' element
-The 'h2' must exist in your HTML